# React Router v4 not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following code for router setup:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'; 
import App from './App'; 

export default () => ( 
  <Router history={browserHistory}> 
    <Route name="demo" path="/mydemo" component={App} /> 
  </Router>
);
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`. in Router (at Router.js:12)    
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at new Router (Router.js:43)
```

Comment: Where are you populating the `browserHistory` variable?

Comment: am just imported after installed package of react router as import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

Comment: what version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
export default () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route name="index" path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>
);

Comment: am using 4 version

Comment: what if you use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`?

Comment: how do you start the server? with` webpack` or?

Comment: am using create-react-app

Comment: still am facing same issue even after changed to hashHistory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have your React-Router v3 and v4 implementations mixed up. Perhaps you upgraded recently?

In any event, try:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

...

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Don't forget to install `react-router-dom` if you haven't already. Also, have a look at the official [**Quick Start**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) guide if you need more info.

Comment: @Ramusesan Glad I could help.

Comment: following also working fine                                                                                                import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';

render(( <Router> <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> </Router> ), document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Link is not working in my case.  i can see the url changed but my component never loads